# Python make loops run faster

Tags: python, optimization

I have made a simple Python 3.9 program:

```
attemptedPass = 0
password = 1234
while True:
    if attemptedPass == password:
        print("PASSWORD FOUND")
        break
    attemptedPass += 1
    print(attemptedPass)
```

which basically tries multiple passwords until it finds the correct one.

The problem is: when running it through Visual Studio 2022, it runs extremely fast (it finds my 6-digit password in about 15 seconds). But, when running it by double-clicking the file, it runs very slowly. What is the reason for that and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know why its running slower on VS2022, but if you want something to run fast, generally it isn't a good idea to print during the loop.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the speed of the IO being done by the `print` on each line.

Comment: `print`ing anything at all takes **much** longer than the actual calculation done by your program.

Comment: 15 seconds is in fact extremely *slow* to check a 6-digit "password" if you're only allowing digits. Without the prints, and with a "password" set to 999999, it takes less than a tenth of a second on my quite old machine.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think I have explained what I am trying to do falsely. Whan I am trying to do is, suppose I don't know the correct password, find the password by trying. So I am trying to simulate a brute force attack to see how much time would it take for a password to be cracked.

Comment: @Alexander yes but then why does it run quickly on Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: @xDev120 Let me frame your question by its opposite: Why would you expect the terminal implementations of Visual Studio and Command Prompt (or wherever else you're running your program) to be equivalently fast?

Comment: No; your explanation was fine, and we understood you perfectly, and what we have to tell you is the same. `print` is slow, and its slowness varies depending on the environment.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel so is there a way to run the program via the command prompt as fast as with the visual studio thing? can you also explain why this happens?

Comment: @xDev120 What everyone is getting at is that these are two different programs, with two different implementations (as far as I can tell, they don't just share some underling terminal component). There's no reason why they would behave equivalently fast. That's not really an issue though, because it's not the point of a terminal to spam useless text and thousands of lines a second, so there's not much reason to optimize for that. *that's useless*. If you really need all these lines, pipe them to an in-memory buffer or file, instead.

Comment: As others have hinted, the printing on every line of your loops is much, much, much slower than everything else your loop is doing. I wouldn't be surprised if your program got 10,000x faster (or more, tbh) if you just remove the print line, or if you made it so the print line only happens on every several thousand iterations instead of every single one

Comment: There is no reason why a program like this *should* print out about every attempt, *anyway*.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, I tried removing the print and it works much faster (20 seconds instead of 60 for password 12345678) But, 20 seconds is much compared to the "one tenth of a second" Karl Knechtel said it would take, so is my computer that trash or I just did something very wrong?

Comment: "depending on the environment" - so can anyone explain what is happening in these different environments such that the timings are different with the same code even with I/O inside the loop?? Different environment meaning Visual vs double click on the same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is `print(attemptedPass)` you can increase the default buffer from 8192 to 2*8192 for windows powershell to approximately match the mvs2022 performance.

##### Code

```py
import time
import io
import sys
import statistics as stats


def speed_test():
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    attemptedPass = 0
    password = 1234567

    while True:
        if attemptedPass == password:
            print("PASSWORD FOUND")
            break
        attemptedPass += 1
        print(attemptedPass)  

    return time.perf_counter() - t0  # sec


def main():
    newbufsize = io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE * 2
    sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedWriter(sys.stdout.buffer, buffer_size=newbufsize))
    data = []
    for _ in range(4):
        e = speed_test()
        data.append(round(e, 1))

    print(data)
    print(f'mean: {round(stats.mean(data), 1)}')

main()
```

##### Output

Windows powershell

```
[18.8, 18.8, 18.8, 18.8]
mean: 18.8
```

mvs2022 with or without

```
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedWriter(sys.stdout.buffer, buffer_size=newbufsize))
```

```
[20.9, 20.9, 20.9, 20.9]
mean: 20.9
```